# D3 Zoom in Ionic

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, d3.js, ionic-framework

I've been for the last few weeks trying to make an interactive D3 map in Ionic- a simple svg that when you select a state produces that states postal code. This code is fine, and works outside of ionic.

However, once it's brought in there, the code seems to blow up on clicking- it resets the svg's center at the previously clicked location. So when you click on Texas, and then click on Wisconsin, the map jolts back to Texas. The panning and zooming works fine otherwise.

I'm wondering if anyone on here has seen any working examples of pan and zooming working in Ionic, or could point out any factors that could be causing this weird behavior.

```
    var zoom = d3.behavior.zoom()
.scaleExtent([1, 4])
.on("zoom", move);

var width = 350;
var height = width / 2;

var topo,projection,path,svg,g;

var tooltip = d3.select("#map").append("div").attr("class", "tooltip hidden");

setup(width,height);

function setup(width,height){
  projection = d3.geo.albersUsa()
    .scale(500)
    .translate([width / 2, height / 2]);

  path = d3.geo.path()
      .projection(projection);

  svg = d3.select("#map").append("svg")
      .attr("width", width)
      .attr("height", height)
      .append("g")
      .call(zoom);

  g = svg.append("g");
}


d3.json("usa.topojson", function(error, usa) {

  var states = topojson.feature(usa, usa.objects.states).features;

  topo = states;
  draw(topo);

});

function draw(topo) {

  var states = g.selectAll(".states").data(topo);

  states.enter().insert("path")
      .attr("class", "states")
      .attr("d", path)
      .attr("post", function(d,i) { return d.properties.postal; })
      .attr("id", function(d,i) { return d.id; });

  states.on("click", function(d, i){
    console.log(d.properties.postal)
  });
}

function redraw() {
  width = 350;
  height = width / 2;
  d3.select('svg').remove();
  setup(width,height);
  draw(topo);
}

function move() {
  var t = d3.event.translate;
  var s = d3.event.scale;  

  g.style("stroke-width", 1 / s).attr("transform", "translate(" + t + ")scale(" + s + ")");
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to create a jsfiddle that reproduce the problem?

Comment: I have the same problem, and would be glad to learn your progress on this problem.

Comment: I guess is that the ionic library conflicts with d3 in terms of touch events. @floribon

Answer (score 0):

I created a pull request to fix the problem. Now it is accepted: https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/pull/4589

So hopefully in the version 1.2, this problem would be eliminated.